# Cannot Import Protocol from Sinch Framework - SinRegionInfo

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, protocols, sinch

I have a project that I have built where I am trying to include the sinch framework for making SMS verification. I added Sinch to the project VIA cocoapods, and also by manually adding the folder/framework to my xcode file system.

The problem i'm having right now is that my version of the CountrySelectionViewController.swift cannot access the SinRegionInfo protocol defined inside of the Sinch framework... i'm not sure what is going wrong. An example of the code/error inside CountrySelectionViewController.swift is here:

var entries: Array`<SINRegionInfo>` = []; ---> Use of undeclared type 'SinRegionInfo'

The strange part is that everything seems to be the same in my project as it is in the sample project, but in the sample project, there is no problem accessing the protocol.

CountrySelectionViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SinchVerification

class CountrySelectionViewController : UITableViewController {

var isoCountryCode: String?

var onCompletion: ((String) -> Void)?

var entries: Array<SINRegionInfo> = [];

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    let regionList = PhoneNumberUtil().regionList(forLocale: Locale.current);
    entries = regionList.entries.sorted(by: { (a: SINRegionInfo, b: SINRegionInfo) -> Bool in
        return a.countryDisplayName < b.countryDisplayName;
    })
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let row = entries.index { (region: SINRegionInfo) -> Bool in
        return region.isoCountryCode == isoCountryCode;
    }
    if row != nil {
        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: Int(row!), section: 0), animated: animated, scrollPosition: .middle);
    }
}
```

Comment: any progress on this? I have same issue